# Spring RequestMapping to consume JSON with big value

Tags: spring

I am writing something  like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

```
public Test test(@RequestBody User user) {
        doSomething();
    }
```

What if one certain number value field in the json request body exceeds the range limit of JAVA Long type? Will it throw a error and how should I catch it?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? If so, please show us the results you found out. If you can't find out how to try it, I'd try to show how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot application throws 400 Bad Request in this case.

For example in case of integer, it will throw error with below message,
JSON parse error: Numeric value (199999999999999999999999) out of range of int

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use large numbers, you should be able to use BigInteger datatype instead, and use USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS in deserialization feature of Jackson.

However, if you want to catch an exception, you can use BindingResult to hold the result of validation. And catch the exception by accessing hasErrors method of BindingResult object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler` to handle exceptions in your rest controllers

The below is a exception handler for `java.lang.RuntimeException` in this handler you can return custom `ResponseEntity`

```
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Error> exceptionHandler(RuntimeException ex){
    LOGGER.error("Exception",ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error("Error on processing",ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The `Error` class can be.

```
public class Error {
    private String message;
    private String detail;

    public Error(String message, String detail) {
        this.message = message;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Error{" +
                "message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", detail='" + detail + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

So the response on exception will some thing like the below.

```
{
  "message": "Error on processing",
  "detail": "JSON conversion problem: Numeric value (11111111111111100000000000000000) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (11111111111111100000000000000000) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 7] (through reference chain: com.seenukarthi.so.User[\"id\"])"
}
```

Sample: https://github.com/seenukarthi/spring-rest-exception